# Probability Distribution Question (Normal Dist?)

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Needed some help with this question.

Q1: The mean of a probability distribution is 97 and the standard deviation is 4. Estimate the probability that an outcome will fall between 90 and 104.

My solution: No other information has been given. Can I assume this is a standard normal distribution and solve accordingly?

Thanks appreciate your help.

Comment: Assume yes, for otherwise you might not be able to solve the problem at all.

Comment: Do you get a answer a answer of 0.92?

Comment: Yes.${}{}{{}}{}$

Comment: @user473207 What do you mean by "this" in "Can I assume **this** is a standard normal distribution and solve accordingly?"

Comment: You can use Chebyshev's inequality to estimate probability from below without any distribution assumptions.